# NHibernate No-Proxy Lazy Load prevents collection from being loaded

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-loading

I have a class hierarchy that I've mapped using table per class hierarchy:

```
               AbstractClass
                     |
        -----------------------------
        |                           |
   ConcreteClassA             ConcreteClassB
```

AbstractClass has a property of type "Status" named "Status", and has a hashed set of "Widgets".

If I set the laziness of the "Status" reference to "no-proxy", my "Widget" collection is not loaded when I attempt to access it. In addition, the concrete subclass will be proxied.

If the laziness of the "Status" reference is set to "proxy", my "Widget" collection will be lazy loaded, as expected.

Why would setting "no-proxy" on a many-to-one reference affect how my collections are lazy loaded? I'm using NHibernate 3.3.2 GA and Fluent NHibernate. The database is iSeries DB2, if that makes any difference.